# Multivalue entity reference synchronization

Tags: 7, entities

I have node type A with Entity Reference **multivalue field** that can reference other nodes of type A (existing). Is there a simple way/module/workflow/ruleset/other to do synchronization as follow:
after saving new node of typa A (ie. nid=112) referring two nodes (ie. nid 66 and 77) I want node 66 and node 77 automatically have references to 112.

Answer (score 3):

Two way references are described in [this drupal.org issue](http://drupal.org/node/1293792)

[Corresponding Entity References](http://drupal.org/project/cer) seems to be consensus solution there, but if it's no good for you, read whole thread, it provides interesting ideas and alternative approaches.